# FOS ElasticaSearch Unrecognized options index_analyzer search_analyzer mappings

Tags: php, symfony, yaml, foselasticabundle

I'm blocked by Symfony error:

> Unrecognized options "index_analyzer, search_analyzer, mappings" under
>   "fos_elastica.indexes.optro.types.technical_assistance"

I use Symfony 3.4.11 and FOS-ElasticSearch 5.03.

What's wrong? File indentation?
Part of Config file:

```
types:
  technical_assistance:
    index_analyzer: my_nGram_index_analyzer
    search_analyzer: my_nGram_search_analyzer
    mappings:
      subject: { boost: 2 }
      description: ~
      equipment_reference: ~
      filename: ~
      trackingNumber: ~
      requester:
        type: "object"
        properties:
          first_name: ~
          last_name: ~
      section:
        type: "object"
        properties:
          name: ~
          translatedNames: ~
      messages:
        type: "object"
        properties:
          content: { boost: 0.5 }
          filename: ~
    persistence:
      driver: orm
      model: Optro\HelpdeskBundle\Entity\TechnicalAssistance
      provider: ~
      listener: ~
      finder:
        service: optro.finder.raw.technical_assistance
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your custom analyzer has to be declared for each relevant fields. As far as i know, you can't declared it globally.

```
types:
    technical_assistance:
         properties:
             subject:
                 boost: 2
                 index_analyzer: my_nGram_index_analyzer
                 search_analyzer: my_nGram_search_analyzer
             description:
                 index_analyzer: my_nGram_index_analyzer
                 search_analyzer: my_nGram_search_analyzer
             ...
```

Comment: I will test soon, and i forward the result

Comment: mappings is still an unrecognized option

Comment: You have to use `properties` instead of `mappings`